# NSFetchedResultController Sorting problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort the nsarray record  as the following:

```
NSArray * name = [entityArray valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

using **NSSortDescriptor** , but it does not show ascending.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch results from core data in sorted format?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your fetch record function.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"column2sort" ascending:YES];   
NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptorArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"CompanyName"   ascending:YES  selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] ;

[companyListArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:lastNameDescriptor]];

[lastNameDescriptor release];

use like this and try

Comment: Actually, I wanna add another sorting after this sorting. For Example,the distance.  I tried to sort the companyListArray,but it already became a string or other unknown data type.